# Existence and Uniqueness of an NLP

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, nonlinear-optimization

I need to solve the following optimisation problem:

\begin{aligned}\max_{\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}} & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1\\
k-1
\end{array}\right)p\left(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)^{k-1}\left(1-p\left(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)\right)^{n-k}\sum_{r=1}^{k}\frac{\alpha_{r}}{k}\\
\text{s.t. } & \alpha_{1}\geq\alpha_{2}\geq\ldots\geq\alpha_{n}\geq0\\
 & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}=1\\
 & \varDelta\left(p;\,\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)=0
\end{aligned}

where at least two allocation "weights" $\alpha_j$ are different, and $\varDelta\left(\cdot\right)$ is a function of $p$ and $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$. To clarify, the probability $p=p\left(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)$ is the solution to the equation $\varDelta\left(p;\,\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)=0$. We know that $p\left(\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)$ is uniquely defined since for all feasible allocations $\varDelta\left(\cdot;\,\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)$ is continuous and strictly decreasing in $p\in\left[0,1\right]$ with $\varDelta(0)>0$ and $\varDelta(1)<0$. Also, $\varDelta$(.) is non-linear in $p$.

I wish to show that this problem has a unique solution and also find it. I struggle with the fact that $p$ is a function of the weights $\alpha_j$ which complicates the objective function.

Here is my attempt to solve it:
I relax the above (original) problem and solve for a *given* $p\in\left[0,1\right]$ the following problem:

\begin{aligned}\max_{\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}} & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\begin{array}{c}
n-1\\
k-1
\end{array}\right)p^{k-1}\left(1-p\right)^{n-k}\sum_{r=1}^{k}\frac{\alpha_{r}}{k}\\
\text{s.t. } & \alpha_{1}\geq\alpha_{2}\geq\ldots\geq\alpha_{n}\\
 & \sum_{k=1}^{n}\alpha_{k}=1
\end{aligned}

The objective function of this relaxed problem is a Binomial expectation over $K$. For every realization $k=1,\ldots,n$, $\sum_{r=1}^{k}\frac{\alpha_{r}}{k}$ is maximized at $\alpha^{*}_{1}=1$, $\alpha^{*}_{2}=...=\alpha^{*}_{n}=0 $ (the arithmetic mean of a monotone sequence has the same monotonicity). Since this holds for every realization, it holds in expectation as well. That is, the solution to the relaxed problem is $\alpha^{*}_{1}=1$, $\alpha^{*}_{2}=...=\alpha^{*}_{n}=0 $. The (unique) $p$ that solves the eliminated feasibility $\varDelta$ constraint of the original problem is also optimal for the original.

Is this proof correct? Since there is a unique solution for the relaxed problem, and $\varDelta(p)=0$ has a unique solution $p$, is this sufficient to prove that the solution is unique. If not, how to show uniqueness rigorously?

Comment: Is $p$ an optimization variable in your original, unrelaxed problem? Based on context it sounds like it is, but it is not written as one of the optimization variables in your current problem formulation.

Comment: Thank you @brenderson. No, my optimization variables are the budget allocation weights $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$.
Given an allocation $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}$ the variable $p$
is uniquely defined via solving $\varDelta\left(p;\,\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{n}\right)=0$.

Comment: I'm still a bit confused. In your original, unrelaxed problem, are you solving for the $\alpha_i$s for a given, fixed value of $p$? Or are you allowing $p$ to vary as the $\alpha_i$s do?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear. The probability $p$ is a function of the allocation weights. Also, we know that given an allocation, we find a unique $p$ (but can't have a closed-form expression for it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on our conversation in the comments, I think $p$ should be considered as an optimization variable in the original problem, to be formal about things.

Under this setting, and under the assumption that your relaxed problem has a unique solution as you mentioned, I believe your argument for the uniqueness of the unrelaxed solution holds true. Here's my argument as to why:

Consider the more general problem of maximizing $f\colon\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ given by $F^* = \sup\mathcal{F}$, where $\mathcal{F}=\{f(\alpha,p) : g(\alpha,p)=0, ~ \alpha \in A, ~ p\in P\}$ and $A$ and $P$ are a fixed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}$, respectively. (In the context of your problem, $f$ is your objective function, $g(\alpha,p)=\Delta(p;\alpha)$, $P=[0,1]$, and $A=\{\alpha\in\mathbb{R}^n:\alpha_1\ge\alpha_2\ge\cdots\ge\alpha_n, ~ \sum_{i=1}^n\alpha_i = 1\}$.) Define $\bar{\mathcal{F}} = \{f(\alpha,p) : \alpha\in A, ~p\in P\}$. Then clearly we have that $\mathcal{F}\subseteq \bar{\mathcal{F}}$, so we obtain the following relaxation:
\begin{equation*}
F^* = \sup\mathcal{F} \le \sup\bar{\mathcal{F}} = \bar{F}^*.
\end{equation*}
Note that we can rewrite the relaxed problem as an infinite number of subproblems over only $\alpha$:
\begin{equation*}
\bar{F}^* = \sup_{p\in P,~\alpha \in A}f(\alpha,p) = \sup_{p\in P}\sup_{\alpha\in A}f(\alpha,p).
\end{equation*}

We will now show that the existence and uniqueness assumptions you provided imply the existence and uniqueness of the unrelaxed solution. In particular, suppose that for all $\alpha\in A$ there exists a unique $p\in P$ satisfying $g(\alpha,p)=0$. Furthermore, assume that $\alpha^*\in A$ is the unique maximizer of $f(\cdot,p)$ for all $p\in P$, i.e. $\arg\max_{\alpha \in A}f(\alpha,p) = \{\alpha^*\}$ for all $p\in P$. Then
\begin{equation}
\bar{F}^* = \sup_{p\in P}f(\alpha^*,p) = f(\alpha^*,p) ~ \text{for all $p\in P$}. \tag{1}\label{eq1}
\end{equation}

By our assumption on $g$, there exists a unique $p^*\in P$ satisfying $g({\alpha}^*,p^*) = 0$. Hence, $(\alpha^*,p^*)$ is feasible for the unrelaxed problem since ${\alpha}^*\in A$, $p^*\in P$, and $g(\alpha^*,p^*)=0$. Therefore,
\begin{equation}
f({\alpha}^*,p^*) \le \sup\mathcal{F} = F^* \le \bar{F}^*. \tag{2}\label{eq2}
\end{equation}
On the other hand, by (\ref{eq1}) we know that $\bar{F}^* = f({\alpha}^*,p^*)$, and therefore all inequalities in (\ref{eq2}) become equalities, i.e.
\begin{equation*}
F^* = \bar{F}^* = f({\alpha}^*,p^*),
\end{equation*}
so $(\alpha^*,p^*)$ is a maximizer of the unrelaxed problem. This shows the existence of the unrelaxed solution. To show uniqueness, note that, since $\alpha^*\in A$ is the unique maximizer of $f(\cdot,p)$ for all $p\in P$ by assumption, it holds that $f(\alpha,p)<f(\alpha^*,p)$ for all $\alpha\in A\setminus \{\alpha^*\}$, for all $p\in P$. Therefore, since $F^* = f(\alpha^*,p^*)$, all maximizers of the unrelaxed problem must be of the form $(\alpha^*,p)$ for some $p\in P$. By the uniqueness assumption on $g$, this implies that $(\alpha^*,p^*)$ is the only maximizer of the unrelaxed problem.

Hopefully I understood your setup and this proves what you were looking for!

Comment: Thank you @brenderson for your effort. I understand your proof but $p$ is a not a decision variable but a function of the decision variables, defined by solving that Δ-equation. I slightly edited the statement of my question now to be clear now. Would you mind checking again?

Comment: Ok, I think I see what you mean. Since $p$ is uniquely defined in terms of $\alpha$, you can express it as $p = h(\alpha)$ for some fixed function $h\colon\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$. This allows you to remove the $\Delta$ constraint and replace $p$ in the objective with $h(\alpha)$, making the problem explicit in only the variable $\alpha$. Is this what you mean?

Comment: If that's the case, consider the new nonlinear program explicit in only $\alpha$ and with $h$ appearing as part of the objective. Then I argue you can introduce a new decision variable $p = h(\alpha)$ and append this constraint to your problem without altering the feasible set of $\alpha$s or the objective. Therefore, simply rewriting the $h(\alpha)$s in the objective as $p$s and maintaining the new constraint, we return to your original formulation of the problem with $p$ as a decision variable (albeit a "dumb"/redundant decision variable, since it is uniquely defined in terms of $\alpha$).

Comment: Essentially, $\sup\{ f(x,g(x)) : g(x) = h(x), ~ x\in X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n \} = \sup\{ f(x,y) : y = h(x), ~ x\in X\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n, ~ y\in \mathbb{R}\}$.

Comment: You are right! I have been way too much into my initial way to prove it, but now I can relate with you. Indeed, $p$ should be thought as another decision variable : ).

Comment: I'm glad we were able to resolve the issue and I hope it all works out correctly for you! Thanks for the interesting question/conversation!